# Could we use Juju without MAAS?

Tags: 14.04, server, juju, maas

Can I install Juju on 1 ubuntu server and deploy my services (or charms) on this server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the local provider to experiment with (https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-local), but not for production services. It will deploy services in LXC containers on your local machine.

Other than that, there is a manual provider (https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-manual), where you tell juju to use specific machines.

Comment: Ok ! But If I want to deploy Openstack with Juju I must use an MAAS environment ? Is that correct ?

Comment: If you want to use the Landscape Autopilot, then yes, you need MAAS. You can also just use the cloud-installer, skip the MAAS installation and select the all-in-one option (I forgot its true name) instead of Landscape (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)